# uniquely identify and element with it's id and class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-spinner

I'm having 6 jquery ui spinners on an html page. I want to hide a image when i'm changing the value of 1st spinner by clicking the spinner buttons(up or down).

The image is hidden when the value of first spinner is changed by the keyboard but when i'm changing through spinner button the image is not hiding.

This is input text which becomes spinner

```
<input type="text" class="save_check controller_performance" id="txtCtrlr" name="txtCtrlr" value="0" style="width: 50px; border-style: none;" />
```

This is the structure when it becomes spinner(copied from firebug)

```
<div class="ui-spinner">
<input type="text" style="width: 50px; border-style: none;" value="0" name="txtCtrlr" id="txtCtrlr" class="save_check controller_performance ui-spinner-box" autocomplete="off">
<button type="button" class="ui-spinner-up">▲</button><button type="button" class="ui-spinner-down">▼</button></div>
```

and the spinner button i'm writing code for

```
$(".ui-spinner-up").click(function (){
    console.log("in click function");
    var parentClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $(this).siblings(".controller_performance").change(hideControllerPerformanceInfo);
    console.log("class is " + parentClass);
       $(parentClass).siblings(".controller_performance").change(function(){
        console.log("changing siblings");
        });
    var id = $('.'+ parentClass+ ':input').attr('id');
    console.log("id is --> " + id);
    if($(this).attr("id") == "txtCtrlr") {
         // hideControllerPerformanceInfo();
         $(".ui-spinner-box").bind("propertychange keyup input paste", hideControllerPerformanceInfo );
    }
});
```

Is there any another way to uniquely identify the first spinner and call the hide function. I cannot write jquery code based on a class as selector, it would be applied to all spinners.

Comment: I'm sorry but it wasn't clear to me. When you click the first spinner's up or down button, your image should hide, is that correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct, the value of input type text is changed when i click on the spinner button and on this event the image should be hide